# Partition formatted with mkfs.ntfs not detected in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, partitioning, ntfs, slackware, fdisk

In my Slackware 13.1 distro I create a partition using fdisk and setting the type to NTFS/HPFS and then I format it using mkfs.ntfs without any additional parameters. However, when I can't open that partition in Windows XP since it is simply missing. Just not identified. What could be the cause and maybe someone had similar experience? Thx!

Comment: Does the drive show up under Disk Management?

Comment: No, it doesn't show up.